# Is it possible to use Windows Forms controls directly on a VB6 form?

Tags: winforms, vb6, winforms-interop

**Is it possible to use a .NET Windows Forms control directly in a VB6 form?**

The goal here would be to use the more up to date .NET controls in a legacy VB6 application. We already have a mixed .NET / VB6 environment.

- I am aware of the [Microsoft InteropForms Toolkit](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3264) but it is described as being used for exporting *custom usercontrols* to VB6 from .NET. This doesn't seem to provide for preexisting controls (but I could be wrong).
- I have tried to simply reference System.Windows.Forms.tlb in a VB6 project as a component library - but it does not allow this to be selected, which seems to imply it has no ActiveX controls inside it.

I'm aware you can easily do the reverse - eg use a VB6 usercontrol on a .NET winforms form. That's not what I need.

---

You can reference the `System.Windows.Forms` assembly in a normal way from VB6 - and wind up with a line such as the following in your VBP:

```
Reference=*\G{215D64D2-031C-33C7-96E3-61794CD1EE61}#2.4#0#C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Windows.Forms.tlb#System_Windows_Forms
```

but this doesn't provide access to place controls on a form.

Comment: Is it worth the pain, over modernizing the VB6 app to VB.NET?

Comment: @HardCode If it's a large code base, sure, it might be too painful.

Comment: @HardCode we are modernizing a large VB6 app to .NET, in an incremental fashion. This may be a useful step.

Comment: I believe you will need to wrap the .NET controls somehow.  Perhaps the Interop Toolkit is not a bad way to go?  One .NET control per UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

I did that before.
I created a control (with the forms control you want use) in .net (exported to tlb using InteropFormsToolkit) and created a vb6 control where I put that .net control. 
It was necessary to map all the properties, events and methods that I wanted to use.
In forms vb6 I added this vb6 control, with the .net encapsulated.
It worked!

Comment: Thanks @Jorge maybe that is the way to go. I was hoping there would be a way to do it without writing wrappers.

Comment: Or just having it done automatically would also be nice.