# How do I wrap winforms to be used n vb6?

Tags: winforms, vb6

I would like to ask if I can use WinForms textbox in a VB6 application.

I do not find any tutorial on this anymore.

Thank you!

Edit:

I have installed the InteropWinformsToolkit and compiled the sample Interop DLL control which was present in the samples.

Then I added a reference to it and called the following which did not work:

```
Option Explicit

Private h As HybridAppControls.VB6Toolbar

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set h = New HybridAppControls.VB6Toolbar
    h.Move 0, 0, 100, 100 'does not work. Raises "Does not support this method / property"
    h.Visible = True
    
    Me.Controls.Add h 'does not work. Raises invalid number of arguments  error

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098223/is-it-possible-to-use-windows-forms-controls-directly-on-a-vb6-form

Comment: To my knowledge, you cannot use the textbox directly.  However, you could build an Interop UserControl that contains the textbox and then drop this onto a VB6 form.  Here is a [good tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18954/Interop-Forms-Toolkit-2-0-Tutorial) that I have used in the past.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Thank you. Unfortunately the tools mentioned in the tutorial are long gone. May I ask you if the tutorial was specific to C#, or could it be used with VB.NET as well?

Comment: I don't find any link for the Toolkit anymore...

Comment: Oh, I found this: https://github.com/hurcane/Microsoft.InteropFormTools.InteropFormProxyGenerator

Comment: Definite dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54098223/is-it-possible-to-use-windows-forms-controls-directly-on-a-vb6-form

Comment: @tmighty I wasn't aware the toolkit was no longer available.  That's too bad because it works well, and I still use it in production to this day.

Comment: @tmighty Yes, the tutorial was in C# but I applied the concepts to my VB projects.

Comment: @BrianMStafford Thanks. When I build the sample HybridAppControls\HybridAppControls\(...)HybridAppControls.dll how am I supposed to use it? I have added a reference to it in VB6. Then I said this, but it wouldn't work (with various errors): Option Explicit

Private h As HybridAppControls.VB6Toolbar

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Set h = New HybridAppControls.VB6Toolbar
    h.Move 0, 0, 100, 100
    h.Visible = True
    
    Me.Controls.Add h

End Sub

Comment: @ps: For better readability I have added the code to my post.

Comment: tmighty found a [GitHub project](https://github.com/hurcane/Microsoft.InteropFormTools.InteropFormProxyGenerator) that seeks to make the toolkit available again. Sounds promising.